# Convert seconds [s] to milliseconds [ms] in Paraview "Plot Selection over Time"

Tags: paraview

After composing my Paraview scene, I realised that I need to represent the units in a "Plot Selection Over Time" filter instead of seconds in milliseconds. How can one accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The long way, modifying only the display:

- manually set the ticks with the advanced option `Bottom Axis Use Custom Label`

The quickest way, modifying the actual scene time:

- use the `Temporal Shift Scale` filter before plotting

Answer (score 0):

The best way (and one of the most important feature of paraview) is that you can setup your selection and you can save the state in a [PvPython](https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/PvPython_and_PvBatch) script. Later you can modify the script by changing the units there. Finally you can save the plot (or even better save the data in a file and later plot them with pgfplot or with another plotter). You can find an example of script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29025148/9455722) (here the plot line feature is used, but in your case when you will setup the state it will be a selection).
For sure this is longer than doing it with the UI, but it allows you to:

- auomatize everything;
- Use the script on a cluster, or when you do not have access to the graphical interface.